# Suppling 5v, 0.02 A (20 mA)

Tags: power-supply, power

In my campus i am using a power supply unit, in order to supply 5V and 0.02A, to my analog circuit that interacts with a microcontroller.

I am unable to go to the university because of work, and i want to take the circuit and the microcontroller to my house for programming work.

It's easy to carry the circuit that resides in a breadboard and the microcontroller, but i cannot take the big power supply.

So i want to provide 5V and 0.02 amps to the circuit.

I have never worked with power supplies before.

From a multi transformer i have in my house, i can get the voltage right.
Heck, even USB proved 5V. I could solder some wires and provide supply to my circuit from the USB cable.

What i don't know is the amps.
How will i be able to provide 0.02A to the circut?

Can i buy smoe power supply wit hthis value, or eevn varying amperes?
Can i create a circuit that will amke sure i am supplying 0.02A?

Comment: The pronoun "I" should be capitalized in English.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit will draw what it needs, apparently **up to** 20mA. So any 5V supply will meet your stated requirement, provided it's capable of 20mA or more (see below).

20mA is a rather small current, so any decent USB charger will work, as will a power bank (with the advantage that you don't need to plug it in if it's charged). You just need to find a way to connect it.

If you have a sensitive analog circuit, there may be other requirements for noise, ripple, regulation, for it to work optimally, but for a typical microcontroller digital circuit, pretty much any such circuit will work.

Use a good quality supply with genuine safety markings, there are some really bad USB chargers out there that are actually dangerous. A spare power supply from an old brand-name router or switch would be a good possibility, and probably free.

Answer (score 0):

With rare exception, most circuits are arranged in **constant-voltage** mode.  That means you supply them a constant voltage, and the circuit knows how to self-limit the current it draws so it doesn't burn up.

(History note: raw LEDs and raw fluorescent tubes are *not* like that, and incandescents are like that only due to herculean effort by Edison. Meanwhile, Tesla resigned himself to lamps requiring **constant-current** mode, and made transformers to do that; which Edison couldn't do because transformers require AC).

As long as your device is like that, you just need to get a 5 volt power supply. Let's see, you could order one from Mouser and have it in a wee--- just kidding, they're sold at every gas station and convenience store. USB blocks output 5 volts. Just get a USB cable and mutilate it to find the 5V and GND.